# How to execute a page ,that contains JS ,in AJAX ,using innerHTML?

Tags: ajax, callback, javascript

I send GET data with AJAX to another file.And on the another file I have `echo "<script>alert('Something');</script>";`.This is displayed dynamicly with AJAX ,i.e

```
var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('edit');
ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

puts the  `<script>alert('Something');</script>` to **div with name edit**.
But it doesn't alert anything.
How to get it work?

**I have mixed html/javascript.**
Here is the code.

```
function ajaxFunctions(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('edit');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }


    var namef = document.getElementById('nameed').value;
    var queryString = "?namef=" + namef;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "try.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

}
```

Maybe to find the **script** tags and to **eval** them?
But how to find the **script** tags?

Comment: i retagged your post. It doesn't had anything to do with jQuery after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to inject a script element in the DOM, just have your script return:

```
alert('Something');
```

And then use `eval(response);` to run it. Or you could add a script element with the `src` attribute pointing to the page that returns your JavaScript into the `<head>` (which is the preferred method).

```
function loadScript(url) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Keep in mind that this wont work for cross-domain requests--the script has to have the same origin as the page running your code. To get around this, you'll have to use a callback.

Comment: It isn't only JS.It's mixed html and js

Comment: I suppose to use replace,but how?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only purpose of setting innerHTML is an attempt to get the JS to execute.  But once the page is loaded, JS won't 'know' that it needs to parse and execute the new text you've changed, so your method won't work.  In this case, what you want is a callback function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I haven't used jQuery, but it looks like you'd simply add a 'complete' property to the settings object you pass to the .ajax() call, like so:

```
 $.ajax({
   // ......

   complete: function(){
     alert('Something');
   }

   // ......
 });
```

In this case, the callback function would execute once the ajax call has completed.  You can pick other events, such as on success, on failure, and so on, if you need to attach your code to a different event.

Comment: Ah, I posted before you'd edited, I assumed you were using the jQuery ajax library.  In any case, I think I misunderstood the issue a bit, the problem is that you don't know what JS code you need to execute until the server generates it for you?  If there are a limited number of responses you could receive from the server, you could have the server return a short string and then switch on that in your handler - if you need to execute any arbitrary JS I guess you could call eval() on it, but I'd be VERY careful with that.

Comment: It won't be a commercial site.But how to find the script tags and eval them?

Answer (score 0):

> But how to find the script tags?

Well, `parent.getElementsByTagName('script')` and then evaling the `data` of the text node inside will do it.

However, inserting content that includes script tags is unreliable and works slightly differently across browsers. eg. IE will execute the script the first time the script node is inserted into any parent, inside the document or not, whilst Firefox will execute script the first time a subtree including the script is added to a node inside the document. So if you're not extremely careful, you can end up executing scripts twice on some browsers, or executing the script at the wrong time, following a further page manipulation.

So don't. Return script that you want to execute separately to any HTML content, eg. using a JSON object containing both the HTML and the JavaScript seperately.

Comment: After  ajaxRequest.send(null); I put
var justexit = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
eval(justexit);
but it isn't working again?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`. You would have to iterate the list and `eval` the `data` of the `Text` node inside each `script` element. Again, don't do this.