# AJAX callback in Inter Explorer

Tags: ajax, callback, synchronization

I have a question about AJAX.. I am using AJAX for my javascript in calling php file,
how ever I noticed that when I run the program in IE callback comes in twice which 
gives me more results than expected while callback comes in in firefox only once..

I want to have just the one reply from callback..

```
this.doPost = function(param) {
        /// make a HTTP POST request to the URL synchronously
        req.open("POST",url, true);
    ...
```

this is the call..

Do you know what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you actually perform the AJAX call and what you do in the callback, you can run into issues - see for example this thread for similar issues:

- [How to execute a page ,that contains JS ,in AJAX ,using innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395663/how-to-execute-a-page-that-contains-js-in-ajax-using-innerhtml)

I suggest you try some proven library instead of using AJAX on the low level. For example, using jQuery you can use `$.ajax`, see e.g. the examples in jQuery documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or some of many other examples you can find on the Net, such as this:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/